# Sound pitches down when using external USB soundcard

Tags: sound, usb, soundcard

Lenovo t420 - Ubuntu 20.04

Since two weeks ago I cannot play audio at the correct pitch when I use my external USB soundcard. This only applies to this current install, the external USB soundcard works fine on a live Ubuntu USB or windows. All audio played through the USB is pitched slowly (about 10%) irrespective of whether played through Rhythmbox, Chrome, VLC or Firefox.

On older versions of Ubuntu the Alsa mixer was visible and configurable.

Any ideas? Anything I can remove to return it to the state it was in a couple of weeks ago. I usually have problems with Ubuntu that require a full re-install two or three times a year (with all the backing up and re-installation of codecs and the days of de-bugging that that entails) and I would really rather avoid it if I can

One further puzzling thing is that live radio plays slowly - not just the sound but the time actually slows down. IE - if I listen to the radio live, every minute of radio takes a minute and 10 +- while still showing as live

Comment: Is there a time delay or does it change the note or both? I ask because you describe a time delay but you mention pitch. I think pitch usually refers to the note or the frequency and not the speed or delay, that is, unless the speed affects the pitch and then it sounds lower as the time is stretched out, affecting the frequency like it would on a record player. This isn't as common with digital and normally timing/speed doesn't affect the pitch.

Comment: Not sure if this will help your problem but the `alsamixer` command is available through the `alsa-utils` package and you'll probably need to use f6 to select your sound card if using USB. There are a few GUI options like `gnome-alsamixer` and `alsamixergui` although, I'm not familiar with these.

Comment: It will be great to attach your USB sound card name and kernel version number, run `uname -a` in a terminal. My wild guess it's about this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1966066, try to use an older kernel if you're running 5.13 on Focal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a fresh install of Ubuntu (Studio) 20.04, on a Focusrite Scarlett Solo, connected via USB (all other Pulse and ALSA audio working fine).

Solved it by following the suggestion [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1966066). Modifying /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, setting:

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

uncommenting it by removing the semicolon at the start, and restarting pulse in a terminal with:

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

Will now test if it remains after a system restart.

Comment: It works after the restart!